# Integrating Canadian WMS with ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, wms, configuration

We are trying to load a Canadian WMS to our ArcGIS Server and I am told the URL should have "arcgis" or "rest" in it for it to work.

This [WMS-Toporama link](http://wms.ess-ws.nrcan.gc.ca/wms/toporama_en?) works find in ArcMap with "Add WMS Server" tool but our web site person cannot seem to load it with our ArcGIS Server. I am not familiar enough with the web site side of things to give a good answer to this problem.

Comment: What is your current setup? ArcGIS Server is more for creating WMS services rather than consuming them.

Comment: I am told we are on FlexViewer 3.0

Comment: Is there more information needed?

Comment: can your web site person provide more information about what is going on? Are you trying to consume the linked WMS within your Flex application? If this is the case the problem has little to do with your ArcGIS Server. Mapperz is assuming that you are using ArcGIS Server to cascade an external WMS so that your Flex application only pulls maps from your server. Can you clarify?

Comment: I received some answers to your questions: "Are you trying to consume the linked WMS within your Flex application?" ...YES...

"Are you using ArcGIS Server to cascade an external WMS so that your Flex application only pulls maps from your server?" ...YES, we are using Arc Server 10.0 FlexViewer 3.0 but we do both pull and post with this application. We pull ESRI mapping services in this fashion all the time...

Answer (score 1):

The toporama WMS you reference is not an ArcGIS WMS service, the message you get from browsing to the service endpoint (as below) tells me that this service is provided by [MapServer](http://mapserver.org/):

> No query information to decode. QUERY_STRING is set, but empty.

As you say this is a perfectly valid WMS and works as such when you reference it in ArcMap.

In some GIS servers (I'm not sure if this is the case with ArcGIS server) you can incorporate another WMS service as a data source, which is sometimes referred to as cascading a WMS.  When cascading a WMS service the only requirement is that the service conforms to the WMS standard, the software that provides the WMS shouldn't be important, and therefore the URL shouldn't be important.